# How to debug ESP32 UDP Server crashing after some days

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

i am using an ESP32 that is doing the following things:

- communicate with INA3221 power monitoring sensors via I2C to measure current and voltage of some singleboard computers
- setup udp server to accept requests for a certain single board computer, send measurements to client
- visualize the current measurements per device using a SSD1306 display via I2C

All these things are done on a separate thread. The threads are created like so:

```
xTaskCreate(start_power_measurements, "ina3221_power_measurement", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE * 8, NULL, 2, NULL);
```

For each client such a thread is created.

### The Issue

My ESP32 served 6 clients but crashed somehow after 2 1/2 days. Unfortunately i don't know how i should debug this. I want to read the logs in order to see what happened but `idf.py monitor` restarted the ESP32 and now logs are gone. In case this happens again I need to know how I can take a look at the logs without restarting the ESP32. They recently added a `--no-reset` option to the command and it works but this only shows logs that are logged after connection. I need a way to take a look at the old logs because I can't be connected to the serial console 24/7.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy problem to solve with an extra ESP32.

Connect GND and TX from the ESP32 you're monitoring to GND and almost any GPIO pin on the second ESP32. Write a very brief program for the second ESP32 that configures UART1 to receive on that pin and writes whatever it receives to flash. After the problem occurs, inspect what the second ESP32 wrote and you should have the information you need.

Alternatively you could have the second ESP32 log to a TCP connection and run `netcat` as a server on a system that will remain online and accessible from the monitoring ESP32, writing its output to a file:

```
nc -l 8000 > output.txt
```

Or log to syslog using a syslog library. You can complicate this as much as you want but the more complicated the more likely it is something else will go wrong. Logging to flash on the monitoring ESP32 has the fewest failure modes and is most likely to get you what you need.

As an alternative, you may be able to use a core dump to analyze the failure. There are some failure modes (particularly hardware-related ones) which won't reliably generate core dumps, but it's possible that they might catch your problem and allow you to analyze it.

Configuring your application to generate a core dump and then analyzing it requires several steps which may change as ESP-IDF continues to evolve, so I'll [link to the official documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/core_dump.html) rather than reiterate them here.

Comment: I really have no exp with microcontrollers so maybe thats a stupid question but i am surpised that this is not possible out of the box. You are really expected to be connected to the serial console 24/7 if you want to monitor / debug your ESP without any extra equipment? ? Anyway, thx for the info, I'll try

Comment: ESP32's and most other microcontrollers do not run a resident operating system like Linux that has protected address spaces and enforces boundaries between programs. If a program on an ESP32 crashes, the ESP32 crashes. There's nothing left on it that's reliably able to report or log the crash. And you still need somewhere to report to. The alternative is to do real debugging using JTAG but that requires a capable computer to be connected the entire time, something you said you weren't able to do.

Comment: There is an alternative which might or might not work for you. I updated the answer with info on it.